# Other option - how to set the value?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

```
1. Member Account Number<span class="bodyCopy"><font color="#ff0000"> * </font></span>: 
<html:select name="reDataForm" property="member.accountNumber" styleClass="formContent"
        style="width:80px" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<html:options collection="<%= WorkConstants.Dropdowns.PACCT %>" property="value"
            labelProperty="label" styleClass="formContent"/>
</html:select>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

Function is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showfield(name){
        if(name=='Other')
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<html:text name="reDataForm" property="member.accountNumber" styleClass="formContent"  maxlength="9" size="9"/>';
        else
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
    }
</script>
```

question is :  if I select option "Other", a text appears below as designed. But the value member.accountNumber is not set into it. I can see the account number as "Other". not the value I entered in the text box. why ? and how do I set this ?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting confused with client side and server side code. The Struts tag `<html:text>` gets rendered on the server side. In your case, you are trying to place that custom tag on the client side (Javascript). The Javascript basically spits out that HTML line and your browser isn't able to interpret what `<html:text>` is because that's a server side custom tag.

**UPDATE**

What you need to do is to place the text as a hidden field, so that Struts can render the custom tag and the bean value:-

```
<html:hidden styleId="accountNumber" name="reDataForm" property="member.accountNumber"/>
```

Then, in your Javascript, you want to get the value from hidden field and set it to `div1`:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showfield(name){
        if(name=='Other')
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML= document.getElementById('accountNumber').value;
        else
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: so how do i do this ? should i use <input type="text" in the script ? that way can I assign the value to member.accountnumber ?

Comment: thanks. sorry.. i'm very new to jsp. can you let me know how to do  :GET VALUE FROM HIDDEN FIELD ?

Comment: I made some changes to my post above. I assigned an id to hidden value using `styleId` so that I can do a `document.getElementById('accountNumber').value` to get the hidden field value.

Comment: where should i use <html:hidden styleId="accountNumber" name="reDataForm" property="member.accountNumber"/> ? after <html:select name="reDataForm" property="member.accountNumber" styleClass="formContent" style="width:80px" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"> <html:options collection="<%= WorkConstants.Dropdowns.PACCT %>" property="value" labelProperty="label" styleClass="formContent"/> </html:select> <div id="div1"></div> ????

Comment: Just put it anywhere in your JSP, but not in your `<script>` tag.

Comment: getting warning message when I give this.

Comment: thanks. What if I wanted use this function for different dropdown menu ? what change do i need to make ?